# SQL Server is giving too much Load on RAM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very puzzled with the problem I am going to let you know.

I have taken shared hosting. But server administration is saying our sites are giving too much load on the server from temp files it is creating.

What could be the reason.... and how to free load from server.

Please Help Me It's urgent.

Comment: Did you only installed an SqlServer or maybe some other software too? Maybe it's not the SQL Server. How do you know?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you need to index your tables.  It could be that your SQL queries are doing expensive table scans.   Can you show us what one of your SQL queries looks like and then provide a schema definition for that table it operates on?   that way people here on Serverfault can correctly diagnose if there is some kind of indexing issue.